# Springboot: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

Trying to connect to the mysql database in springboot using the following configuration:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/community?Unicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=America/Boston
    username: root
    password: 01021234
    hikari:
      pool-name: DateHikariCP
      minimum-idle: 5
      idle-timeout: 180000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      auto-commit: true
      max-lifetime: 1800000
      connection-timeout: 30000
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1
```

It's giving me the exception `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

The odd thing is, I have another project where I use almost the same configuration, but it is working fine without any error:

```
# DataSourceProperties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/community?characterEncoding=utf-8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=America/Boston
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=01021234
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=15
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=30000
```

I tried changing the url to the following and it is now working:

```
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/community?user=root&password=01021234&Unicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=America/Chicago
```

But I am so confused now as to why the first snippet of the code I posted did not work.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the URL "as is" from the properties file where it works to yaml? Spring boot should be capable to handle yaml and properties in the same way in general. I The idea is to understand whether this question has anything to do with spring boot at all (if it won't work) or we're talking about the meaning of connection params to mysql

Comment: Yes I did try that, and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what the problem was after hours of searching:

if the password consists of only number then the correct way to define it in the yml file should be:

```
password: '01021234'
```